# Find a matrix $M$ such that $M^TAM = I$

Tags: matrices

I have that my matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}4&0&3\\0&1&0\\3&0&4\end{bmatrix}$,

I've done diagonalization but now finding a matrix $M$ and its transpose acting as a conjugate for the identity matrix seems a bit out of my reach.

Any help would be appreciated .[image]

Did I orthonormalize my vectors accordingly?

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric, it's possible to find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$, and then the change of basis matrix $M$ will be orthogonal, i.e. $M^T=M^{-1}$.

Comment: @carmichael561 oddly enough, we calculated that matrix the problem before but it was named something different. Let me do some calculations and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Diagonalize $A$ by an orthogonal matrix $N$. If the resulted diagonal matrix $D$ has positive entries on diagonal (i.e: $A$ has only positive eigenvalues), then 
$$A=N^tDN = \left(N^t\sqrt{D^{-1}}\right) I \left(\sqrt{D^{-1}}N\right).$$
Hence we can take $M=\sqrt{D^{-1}}N$.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ defines a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $(\,\cdot\,{,}\,\cdot\,)_A\colon \mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$, $(v,w)\mapsto v^TAw$. Now, use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to orthonormalize the standard basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$. If we denote the orthonormal basis we get by $v_1,v_2,v_3$, then $M$ is the matrix with $i$-th column $v_i$ ($i=1,2,3$).